# How to make session_state persist after button click in streamlit

Tags: python, button, streamlit

I'm encountering an issue with Streamlit where I'm trying to allow the user to modify text using `st.text_input` and then display the modified text when a button is clicked. However, the modified text is not persisting as expected in the session state.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```py
import streamlit as st

# Initialize session state
if 'text' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.text = "original"

if st.button("show"):
    # Allow the user to modify the text
    st.session_state.text = st.text_input("Edit Text", value=st.session_state.text)

# Display the modified text
st.markdown(st.session_state.text)

if st.button("show again"):
    # Display the modified text
    st.markdown(st.session_state.text)
```

Despite using `st.text_input` to modify the text, the "show again" button still displays the original text, not the modified one. I've tried using `st.text_area` as well, but the issue persists.

Why is the modified text not persisting in the session state as expected? How to make it persist as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening due to two things:

- The script is rerun every time a button is clicked
- 'text' is changed when the first button is clicked, so the update lags behind in the session state.
  This is even listed as a case in the documentation under [Buttons to modify st.session_state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/button-behavior-and-examples)
   section.

There are two ways to fix the issue.

### Option 1: Change the way `text` is initialized in the session state

We can use `get` since `st.session_state` is like a dict (or an if-else block) to initialize the `text` key so that on script re-run, the `text` value persists across "sessions"; if it's the first time, its value will be `'original'` but for the subsequent runs, it will be whatever it was in the previous session.

```py
import streamlit as st

# Initialize session state
st.session_state.text = st.session_state.get('text', 'original')

if st.button("show"):
    # Allow the user to modify the text
    st.text_input("Edit Text", key='text')        # <--- set using the key kwarg

# Display the modified text
st.markdown(st.session_state.text)

if st.button("show again"):
    # Display the modified text
    st.markdown(st.session_state.text)
```

### Option 2: Use callback function

Another option is to define a callback function which is activated on button click (to show again). The function updates the session state with the current value of `text`, so that it persists through the subsequent script re-runs.

```py
import streamlit as st

def update_text(value):                     # <--- define callback function
    st.session_state.text = value

# Initialize session state
if 'text' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.text = 'original'

if st.button("show"):
    # Allow the user to modify the text
    st.text_input("Edit Text", key='text')

# Display the modified text
st.markdown(st.session_state.text)

if st.button("show again", on_click=update_text, args=[st.session_state.text]):      # <--- invoke the callback
    # Display the modified text
    st.markdown(st.session_state.text)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, that is very good for this question. Then I discover another issue, so I asked another question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591482/how-to-update-session-state-in-text-area-in-streamlit